# python/sqlachemy/ibmdb2 - sqlAlchemy insert with Db2 for i, AS400?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, db2, db2-400

Trying to use sqlAlchemy with IBM Db2 AS400 (IBM i7.2) database. but get an error while adding objects in the database via sqlAlchemy query.

```
class Client(Base):
    """
    Client Account Schema
    """
    __tablename__ = 'client'
    client_id = Column('client_id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    client_name = Column('client_name', String(200))
    client_address = Column('client_name', Text)

input_client_data = {'client_name': 'test', 'client_address': 'client address'}

with conn.db_session() as session:
    client = Client(**input_client_data)
    session.add(client)
    session.commit()
```

> **Error** - pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'lastrowid

Also we are using IBM i access ODBC drivers to connect to Db2. My connection string is below:

`ibm_db_sa+pyodbc400://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}`

1. SQL Alchemy version: 1.3.6
2. IBM DB SA version: 0.3.5
3. Python: 3.5
4. Platform: Ubuntu 16.04

Details of drivers -

```
[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description=IBM i Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
Driver64=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading=0
DontDLClose=1
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: The above shows postgresql code, but you say Db2?!

Comment: The following IBM Cloud tutorial uses Db2 and SQLAlchemy: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats/blob/master/backend/ghstats.py

Answer (score 3):

This was ibm_db_sa library issue. They have updated their library. Please follow below link for more details
[Please follow this link for more details](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ibm_db/b--H0jTS4CE)

[Github link](https://github.com/abhi7436/python-ibmdbsa/commit/6345c88b1b4732b062f787d7a78f947086005226)

Note: They haven't release this change yet. But you can access develop repository.